# CKeditor 4.8 not removing styles on paste

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

We recently upgrade our CKeditor to 4. (was a big jump, we were on I think 4.3) and how when a user pastes in code, the editor is not automatically removing styling, specifically font and text color. I do have `forcePasteAsPlainText : true` in my config, but I can reliably reproduce pasting in text that preserves the font color (ex: red) as it was in an email. How can I make it so all text pasted in is stripped of HTML styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that this happens when you use Paste from Word plugin, because according to [forcePasteAsPlainText](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-forcePasteAsPlainText) info:

> Whether to force all pasting operations to insert on plain text into
>   the editor, losing any formatting information possibly available in
>   the source text.
>
> **Note: paste from word (dialog) is not affected by this configuration.**

So, I would use forcePasteAsPlainText and disable this plugin with:

```
forcePasteAsPlainText : true,
removePlugins: 'pastefromword'
```

Comment: what should be full syntax to set `removePlugins: 'pastefromword'`

Comment: I don't understand. It is exactly as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Please check which CKEditor version you use. It can be found at the top of `ckeditor/CHANGES.md` file. If you are not using latest 4.8.0, please upgrade.

While there were some problems with `forcePasteAsPlainText` in earlier versions, having that option set and pasting HTML should filter it as expected in latest editor 4.8.0.

If you also wish to clear all MS Word formatting then just like @Wizard has written, you can remove the `pastefromword` plugin. Alternatively if you wish to remove only certain styles, you can use [afterPasteFromWord](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-afterPasteFromWord) event where you can get to pasted HTML through `event.data.dataValue` and change it the way you like.